# Search java file containing a specific word in Eclipse like Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

How can I search a java file with a word containing that particular search result in Eclipse like I can in Intellij?

Example: ctrl + shift +r, search the word "Developer"

It only searches for the file names with "developer" in the beginning and then every other letter after that. That's not what I want.

I have to type in "CommandDev" just so the file I am looking for called "CommandDeveloper" will show up in the results. I don't like that.

In Intellij, you just type "Dev" and it'll show every single java file containing that search result, such as:

"CommandDeveloper"
"Developersets"
"Developerpresets"
"ServerDeveloper"
etc.

In Eclipse, if I type "Dev"

It'll just show "Developersets" and "Developerpresets"

But, in Intellij, it'll show all 4 of the files containing the search "Dev"

I already spent 40 minutes searching on Google, Stackoverflow, and Eclipse itself to find out. No luck. It's dumb to not have it in their tools.

Comment: Please no one say "try ctrl + shift + t" as that is the same thing but for class files rather than java files.

Comment: no, it is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`  [:-)   on my eclipse, since I defined that as a short-cut to `File Search` - Menu: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Answer (score 1):

There is a Menu item Search. From there select File.

You will get a screen like this one:

[image]

Here you can enter what you want to look for.

Narrow the files to check, like *.java or just leave * to look everywhere.

And set the scope of the search.

This will provide the results in a search panel organized in a tree.

Comment: Thank you for this. You have also helped me with my struggles. goat #2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use wildcards (*). eg. *Dev*

Comment: Thank you for this. You have helped me with my struggles. goat